# How to share Contact in my ios App?

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact

I would like to share any contact from my contact book using my custom chat app. Is there a way to fetch file related to contact and send it to the server?

I would like to avoid iterate over all possible properties of the contact, create dictionary and send it. Can I fetch any file using iOS Contact Framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all contracts in array using cncontactstore, array contains all contacts, you can convert return array to JSON and send it to server.

```
let store = CNContactStore()
let contacts = try store.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName("Appleseed"), keysToFetch:[CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey])
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone stumbling over this question:

You can convert an instance of `CNContact` to `Data` with `CNContactVCardSerialization` which can be send to the server:

```
let contactStore = CNContactStore()
let keysToFetch = [
    CNContactNamePrefixKey,
    CNContactFamilyNameKey,
    CNContactNameSuffixKey,
    CNContactPostalAddressesKey,
    CNContactEmailAddressesKey,
    CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,
    CNContactBirthdayKey
] as [Any]

var allContainers: [CNContainer] = []
do {
    allContainers = try contactStore.containers(matching: nil)
} catch {
    print("Error fetching containers")
}

var contacts: [CNContact] = []

for container in allContainers {
    let fetchPredicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInContainer(withIdentifier: container.identifier)

    do {
        let containerResults = try contactStore.unifiedContacts(matching: fetchPredicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch as! [CNKeyDescriptor])
        contacts.append(contentsOf: containerResults)
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching containers")
    }
}

for contact in contacts {
    
    do {
        let contactVCard = try CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: [contact])
        // Send contactVCard
    }
    catch {
        print("Error converting contact to vcard.")
    }
```

To convert the data back to an instance of `CNContacts`, assuming that `data` is the data you received from the server:

```
do {
    let contact = try CNContactVCardSerialization.contacts(with: data)
}
catch {
    print("Error converting data to CNContact.")
}
```